# Find common substring in multiple words and remove it

Tags: bash, nlp, substring

I'm still green in scripting and don't know if this is even possible.

I have a lexicon with lemmas and their inflections, and I want to extract the inflectional paradigms.

Sample file (4 tab separated columns):

```
sb. 1   sommer  ;sommer;sommeren;sommerens;sommers;somrene;somrenes;somre;somres
sb. 1   lim ;lim;limen;limens;lims;limene;limenes;lime;limes
vb. 2   spise   ;spise;spis;spist;spiser;spisende;spiste;spises;spistes
adj.    2   sjov    ;sjov;sjove;sjovt
```

I can't figure out how to achieve this, but a possible solution could maybe be something like these two steps.

Step 1:
Find the longest substring of col3 that matches all words in col4 from the beginning of the word. The result is printet in col5.

```
sb. 1   sommer  ;sommer;sommeren;sommerens;sommers;somrene;somrenes;somre;somres    som
sb. 1   lim ;lim;limen;limens;lims;limene;limenes;lime;limes    lim
vb. 2   spise   ;spise;spis;spist;spiser;spisende;spiste;spises;spistes spis
adj.    2   sjov    ;sjov;sjove;sjovt   sjov
```

Step 2:
Remove col5 from the beginning of all the words in col4. The result is printet in col6.

```
sb. 1   sommer  ;sommer;sommeren;sommerens;sommers;somrene;somrenes;somre;somres    som ;mer;meren;merens;mers;rene;renes;re;res
sb. 1   lim ;lim;limen;limens;lims;limene;limenes;lime;limes    lim ;;en;ens;s;ene;enes;e;es
vb. 2   spise   ;spise;spis;spist;spiser;spisende;spiste;spises;spistes spis    ;e;;t;er;ende;te;es;tes
adj.    2   sjov    ;sjov;sjove;sjovt   sjov    ;;e;t
```

Comment: Almost anything is possible, although you should probably show what you've attempted.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.